# creating NPAPI plugin to access chrome DOM details

Tags: google-chrome, npapi, browser-plugin

I have written a NPAPI plugin(using Npruntime sample), I want to use this plugin to get DOM details of the current tab opened in Chrome browser. I am planning to use content script to get DOM details. Is there any other way better then this?

I am new to this.

Comment: I'm not sure about the other way but I can say content script get the job done.

Comment: benjamin, thanks for reply. could you suggest me some links to start with..

Comment: Judging by how well you seem to understand how everything is working, you might want to try using FireBreath -- it simplifies a lot of the pain in npapi plugins. (www.firebreath.org)